# Why it is impossible to transmit a WebSocket through socket?

Tags: serialization, websocket, dart

How to pass WebSocket object over Websocket?

```
ws.onOpen.listen((e) {
    outputMsg('Connected');
    WebSocket otherWebSocket = ...;
    ws.send(otherWebSocket); // does not work
  });
```

Comment: *"does not work"* What happens instead? Probably a web socket cannot be serialized and deserialized in  a sensible way.

Comment: This is just not possible. At some point the WebSocket wraps an OS native socket and you cannot meaningfully serialize an OS socket in any way.

Comment: I thought so. RTC doesn't develop. Connections between browsers it is possible while to forget about p2p...

Comment: Can you fax a fax machine? Can you send a telephone over a telephone call?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: I simply wanted to exchange sockets via the server between browsers and to interact further without server.

Comment: You can't exchange Sockets. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the existing comments it makes no sense to directly serialise an object like a web socket. However, there is a trick that I've seen done in Python which *may* be useful here. Apologies if this is a bit vague; I know no Dart.

The trick involves writing a class that would wraps a  WebSocket and has a method that is called for serialisation. The class constructor would need to store the constructor parameters.

The serialisation method could then serialise these constructor parameters and any other existing 'state' data (e.g. bytes as yet unread from the web socket, any data pertinent to the conversation so far with the server such as keys, client ID, etc) and **close** the WebSocket.

The recipient would be able to create a new WebSocket based on those parameters and resume interactions with the server based on that state data.

Obviously this would require the server at the other end of the socket to cooperate in the closing and re-opening of the socket and carrying on as if nothing had happened. If the server isn't going to do that then this technique will not work.

The [Python code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#handling-stateful-objects) I'm referring to deals with how to serialise a file descriptor. All it does is serialise the file's path and name, the current file position, read/write mode, etc. This allows the recipient of the serialised file to re-open the file in exactly the same state as it had been previously.